# uiswitch default text change

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiswitch

I am trying to use a UISwitch controller but set its default text to "Yes/No" instead of "On/off". What is the easiest way to do that? Well is it doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately in german language, but the source code is readable and it works well:

http://www.mobile-dev.de/iphone-code-schnipsel/34-iphone-user-interface/192-aendern-des-textes-von-uiswitch-elementen.html

But you should read the documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html

`The UISwitch class is not customizable.`

I do not know if it is allowed and you will get trouble in the Apple approval process.